# Prove that $5\mid x\,$ if $\,x, y \gt 1 $ satisfy $2x^2 - 1=y^{15}$

Tags: number-theory

If $x\gt 1$ and $\,y\gt 1,$ with $ x, y \in \mathbb N$ so  that $(x,y)$ satisfies the equation $$2x^2-1=y^{15},$$ then prove that $5\mid x$.

$\mod {10}$ gave me just what the last digit of y can be.

Comment: Do you mean $y^{15}$? And I suppose that $x, y\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Note that we have a problem if $x=y=1$.

Comment: What if you set x,y>1?

Comment: The equation has no solution for $y$ under one million.

Comment: So if the equation had a solution the right part of the equation would have over 90 digits.

Comment: What is the source of this conjecture?

Comment: I found it among other problems that my professor gave me 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.

For example if $x=1, y=1$ we have $2x^2 - 1 = y^{15}$, but of course $5$ does not divide $1$

Comment: In the question it is stated that $x>1$ and $y>1$.

Comment: @egreg the question has been edited since I answered it! :)

Answer (score 0):

apply fermat, so $y^{15}\equiv y^3 \bmod 5$. So you have $2x^2\equiv y^3+1$. now cubes $\bmod 5$ are $1,3,2,4,0$. This tells us the statement is false, because when $y^3\equiv 1$ we get $2x^2\equiv 2$ and $x$ can be $1$ or $4 \bmod 5$

Comment: It's just a hint that the statement *may* be false.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right

Comment: What it tells you is that if the problem is true you need $y$ to be congruent to $-1\bmod 5$ every time the equation holds.

Comment: The OP has edited the question: $y>1$ and $x>1$. This excludes the case $y^3\equiv 1$

Comment: yeah, I'm gonna programm to see if I can find a counter.

Comment: I searched for solutions with $y$ under one million and I found none, so I suspect there are no solutions to the equation.